# Request permissions in main activity

Tags: android

I have an application which records and stores audio on the device. My main activity contains a bunch of buttons to other activities. These other activities are the ones that do the actual audio recording.

My main activity is set up as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button mSmallVowel;
    private Button mSayCat;
    private Button mCough;
    private Button mSaySentence;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String sep = File.separator;
        String newFolder = "AudioRecordingTest";
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + newFolder);
        myNewFolder.mkdir();

        mSmallVowel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSmallVowel);
        mSmallVowel.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSayCat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSayCat);
        mSayCat.setOnClickListener(this);
        mCough = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCough);
        mCough.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSaySentence = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaySentence);
        mSaySentence.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSmallVowel:
                Intent small_vowel_intent = new Intent(this, SmallVowel.class);
                this.startActivity(small_vowel_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.btnSayCat:
                Intent say_cat_intent = new Intent(this, SayCat.class);
                this.startActivity(say_cat_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.btnCough:
                Intent cough_intent = new Intent(this, Cough.class);
                this.startActivity(cough_intent);
                break;
            case R.id.btnSaySentence:
                Intent say_sentence_intent = new Intent(this, SaySentence.class);
                this.startActivity(say_sentence_intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And all the other activities look like the following:

```
public class SaySentence extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;
    private TextView mStatus;
    private TextView mRecorded;

    //folder initialization
    private String sep = File.separator;
    private String mChildFolder = "SaySentence";
    private String mExtStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    private File mChildFile = new File(mExtStorageDirectory + sep + "AudioRecordingTest" + sep + mChildFolder);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_say_sentence);

        mChildFile.mkdir();

        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        mRecorded = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRecorded);

    }

    public void startSpeaking(View view) {
        //clear text
        mRecorded.setText("");

        try {
            beginRecording();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopSpeaking(View view) {
        try {
            stopRecording();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void beginRecording() {
        ditchMediaRecorder();

        //get number of files already in sub-folder and increment the audio filename accordingly
        File[] filesInFolder = mChildFile.listFiles();
        if (filesInFolder != null) {
            int count = filesInFolder.length;
            OUTPUT_FILE = mExtStorageDirectory + sep + "AudioRecordingTest" + sep + mChildFolder + sep + "saysentence" + (count+1) + ".3gpp";
        }
        else {
            OUTPUT_FILE = mExtStorageDirectory + sep + "AudioRecordingTest" + sep + mChildFolder + sep + "saysentence0" + ".3gpp";
        }

        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        mStatus.setText("Recording");

        if(outFile.exists()){
            outFile.delete();
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recorder.start();

    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mStatus.setText("Recording Stopped");
        mRecorded.setText("Audio file saved to: " + OUTPUT_FILE);

        if(recorder != null){
            recorder.stop();
        }

    }

    private void ditchMediaRecorder() {
        if(recorder != null) {
            recorder.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Since in Android 6.0 permissions have to be asked at run time, I would like to make it so that the main activity requests all the permissions I require in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.soufinrahimeen.audiorecordingtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_medical"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SmallVowel" />
        <activity android:name=".SayCat" />
        <activity android:name=".Cough" />
        <activity android:name=".SaySentence"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have looked at the official docs on [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), however, the official tutorial makes it seem like I need to ask for permissions in the activities that actually record and save the audio.

I would like to make it so that the MainActivity requests all the required permissions, and once the user enables them, it allows them to use the rest of the application without any issue.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: how about you request the permissions in MainActivity, and all your other activity extends from MainActivity?

Comment: Permissions are granted for the application (package), not the individual activities. Simply use the sample codes given in the docs in your main activity and you will be set.

Comment: The previous suggestion is alot intuitive > Your `MainActivity extends to a BaseActivity` while the baseactivity implements the Permission logic. But I still prefer if you ask permission when you only need it. A good developer will always *focus on the users comfort* than himself.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having the same code across 4 activities. If I can initialize the permissions in MainActivity, it makes it easier for the rest of the application to function properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines to check mulitple permissions in your code:

```
public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 100;

// function to check permissions
    private void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) + ContextCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                (getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                .RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }

        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                .RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // put your function here

    }
}


 // Function to initiate after permissions are given by user
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean recordPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean writeExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if(recordPermission && writeExternalFile)
                {
                    // put your function here
                }
            }
            else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                    .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                            MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do I put this in my MainActivity?

Comment: Yes and put checkPermission() in onCreate()

Comment: Thank you, its working as planned! What is the proper procedure to follow when permission is not allowed? I would like to fill up the else blocks where permission is not granted, but I;m not sure what to do in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;
    private static final int REQUEST = 112;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    {
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
        } 
        else 
        {
            //do here
        }
    } else {
        //do here
    }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to permissions.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```